# Is PoE without LAN input possible?

Tags: networking

I have an access point which requires PoE input, however that access point can also work as a WiFi extender which means it doesn't need any LAN input, it just needs the power input.
Can I use a generic PoE injector, let's say like this one
[image: poe injector]

and just plug the PoE output cable, without plugging any LAN input cable? Or does the whole PoE mechanism requires LAN input too?
Is this an equipment specific behavior?

Comment: It should work, at least there are no technical reasons why it should not work.  Basically, the adapter is getting the power from the plug and send it down the POE line.

Comment: Does your AP want passive PoE or 802.3af?

Comment: @grawity I don't know that. It's a wdap-c7200ac. Any thoughts?